# Private Key JWT Client Authentication for OIDC : A valid OAuth client could not be found for client_id

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to implement Private Key JWT Client Authentication for OIDC following reference link:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Private+Key+JWT+Client+Authentication+for+OIDC but getting the above mentioned error when tried

But getting error : A valid OAuth client could not be found for client_id: "xxxxx",

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this blog to configure Client authentication with Private-Key-JWT in WSO2 IS. https://medium.com/@piraveenaparalogarajah/client-authentication-with-private-key-jwt-using-wso2-identity-server-ae5c245ecb84.

According to the error:

> A valid OAuth client could not be found for client_id: "xxxxx"

Please check whether the JWT assertion that you send has a valid "iss" and "sub" that matches to the client-id of the configured SP. A valid JWT should be as below:

```
{
 “typ”: “JWT”,
 “alg”: “RS256”,
 “kid”: “piraveena”
}
{
 “iss”: “CAeFC1u5I0SZvh5FfYgYk2IMRNsa”,
 “sub”: “CAeFC1u5I0SZvh5FfYgYk2IMRNsa”,
 “exp”: 1581752233,
 “iat”: 1581748633,
 “jti”: “10003”,
 “aud”: “https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token"
}
```

According to the [OIDC spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ClientAuthentication) which states about client authentication, the claims should be as follows

> iss: [REQUIRED] Issuer. This must contain the client_id of the OAuth
>   Client.
>
> sub: [REQUIRED] Subject. This must contain the client_id of the OAuth
>   Client.
>
> aud: [REQUIRED] Audience. The aud (audience) Claim. A value that
>   identifies the Authorization Server as an intended audience. The
>   Authorization Server must verify that it is an intended audience for
>   the token. The Audience should be the URL of the Authorization
>   Server’s Token Endpoint.

So please verify the jwt-assertion.